# Class constructor DayTableView cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using angular 16 and trying to make a calendar with events.
I am using fullCalendar.

When I try to run my code from the documentation I get the error:

> "vendor.js:97792 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor DayTableView
> cannot be invoked without 'new'"

And I cannot find the DayTableView with a global search through my application. Can someone help me fix it?

[image]

this is my tsconfig.json file, html and typescript if u scroll down u see more. Thx!

````
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitOverride": true,
      "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "useDefineForClassFields": false
    },
    "ts-node": {
      "esm": true
  },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]


}```


I tried to google it and change my target statement in config.json file but it didn't work. I also tried installing it again.

<div class='demo-app'>

  <div class='demo-app-sidebar'>
    <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
      <h2>Instructions</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Select dates and you will be prompted to create a new event</li>
        <li>Drag, drop, and resize events</li>
        <li>Click an event to delete it</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
      <label>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          [checked]='calendarVisible'
          (change)='handleCalendarToggle()'
        />
        toggle whole calendar
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
      <label>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          [checked]='calendarOptions().weekends'
          (change)='handleWeekendsToggle()'
        />
        toggle weekends
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
      <h2>All Events ({{currentEvents.length}})</h2>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let event of currentEvents()'>
          <b>{{event.startStr}}</b>
          <i>{{event.title}}</i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='demo-app-main'>
    <full-calendar *ngIf='calendarVisible()' [options]='calendarOptions()'>
      <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
        <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
        <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
      </ng-template>
    </full-calendar>
  </div>

</div>
html

    import { Component, signal, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions, DateSelectArg, EventClickArg, EventApi } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-calender',
  templateUrl: './calender.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calender.component.css']
})
export class CalenderComponent {
  calendarVisible = signal(true);
  calendarOptions = signal<CalendarOptions>({
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
      listPlugin,
    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)
    /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
    eventAdd:
    eventChange:
    eventRemove:
    */
  });
  currentEvents = signal<EventApi[]>([]);

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  handleCalendarToggle() {
    this.calendarVisible.update((bool) => !bool);
  }

  handleWeekendsToggle() {
    this.calendarOptions.mutate((options) => {
      options.weekends = !options.weekends;
    });
  }

  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    const title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay
      });
    }
  }

  handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
      clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
  }

  handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
    this.currentEvents.set(events);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // workaround for pressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  }

}
typescript
````

Comment: You need to provide code you are using.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue so we can help you more easily. See also [ask]